# Declaring the templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013

```
// stdafx.h 

// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//


#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Animal.h"

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here

class Animal
{
private:
    int itsWeight;
public:
    Animal(int);
    Animal();
    ~Animal() {}
    int getWeight() const { return itsWeight; }
    void Display() const;
};


template <class T>
class Array
{
private:
    T *pType;
    int itsSize;
    const int defaultSize = 10;
public:

    //constructors
    Array(int itsSize = defaultSize);
    Array(const Array &rhs);
    ~Array() { delete[] pType; }

    //operators
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
    T& operator[](int offSet){ return pType[offSet]; }
    const T& operator[](int offSet) const { return pType[offSet]; }

    //methods of Access
    int getSize() const { return itsSize; }
};

//constructor
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int size) :
itsSize(size)
{
    pType = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        pType[i] = 0;
    }
}

//copy-constructor
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array &rhs)
{
    itsSize = rhs.getSize();
    pType = new T[itsSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < itsSize; i++)
    {
        pType[i] = rhs[i];
    }
}

//operator prisvoeniya
template <class T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(const Array &rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs)
      return *this;
    delete[] pType;
    itsSize = rhs.getSize();
    pType = new T[itsSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < itsSize; i++)
    {
        pType[i] = rhs[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

//this is the file "Animal.cpp"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animal.h"

Animal::Animal()
{
    itsWeight = 0;
}

Animal::Animal(int weight)
{
    itsWeight = weight;
}

void Animal::Display() const
{
    cout << itsWeight;
}
// the main function

#include "stdafx.h"

int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

Array<int> theArray;    //Integer array
Array<Animal> theZoo;   //Animal array
Animal *pAnimal;

//filling the array
    for (int i = 0; i < theArray.getSize(); i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = i * 2;
        pAnimal = new Animal[i * 3];
        theZoo[i] = *pAnimal;
        delete pAnimal;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < theArray.getSize(); j++)
    {
        cout << "theArray[" << j << "]:\t";
        cout << theArray[j]<<"\t\t";
        cout << "theZoo[" << j << "]:\t";
        theZoo[j].Display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that: The compiler gives me the errors

> Error  1   error C2648: 'Array<int>::defaultSize' : use of member as default parameter requires static member
>   d:\documents\work\c++ files\tigrans\homework10\templates\templates\templates\animal.h   28  1   Templates
>
> Error  2   error C2648: 'Array<Animal>::defaultSize' : use of member as default parameter requires static member
>   d:\documents\work\c++ files\tigrans\homework10\templates\templates\templates\animal.h   28  1   Templates

Anybody can help me to understand that. I change the

```
const int defaultSize=10;
```

to

```
static const int defaultSize=10
```

then there is not errors but in that time show *Debug Assertion Failed!*

Comment: You definitely must define `static const int defaultSize=10;`. The assertion failure is very likely due to **another bug** eslewhere in your code.

Comment: `pAnimal = new Animal[i * 3]; delete pAnimal;` Your program exhibits undefined behavior: what's allocated with `new[]` must be deallocated with `delete[]`. In any case, you likely meant `new Animal(i * 3)` - parentheses, not square brackets.

Comment: You might want to indicate where each file begins, by naming it. Insert a headline `###"filename" (no spaces at the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code is dodgy

```
{
    pAnimal = new Animal[i * 3];
    theZoo[i] = *pAnimal;
    delete pAnimal;
}
```

The first line allocates an array of `i*3` `Animal`s, using their default constructor (which makes an `Animal` with `itsWeight=0`). In the second line you assign the first these newly allocated `Animal`s to `theZoo[i]`. Finally, the third line tries to de-allocate the `Animal`s.

The last line contains an error, since you call `delete` on a pointer obtained with `new []`.

The whole concept of creating objects on the heap only to immediately destroy them is quite dubious -- perhaps you come from another programming language, where this is the only way to create things? First, you could simply use an automatic variable

```
{
    Animal a;   // or a(i*3);
    theZoo[i] = a;
}
```

or yet briefer

```
{
    theZoo[i] = Animal(i*3);
}
```

(Note the if you would use a `std` container, you could say `theZoo.emplace_back(i*3);`, avoiding the copy of `Animal`.)